# Resize the content of a flexbox when browser width changes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like the content inside my flexbox to change size when I resize the browser (i.e. words and images shrink proportionally).

Inside the flexbox, I have two elements: some text on the left, and an image on the right.

```
<div id="flexbox">
    <div id="text">
        Some text
    </div>
    <img src="images/img.png" alt="" id="image" width="400px" height="414px">
</div>

#flexbox {
    background-image:url("images/board.png");
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row no-wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
}

#text {
    margin-left:10%;
    width:40%;
}

#image {
    margin-right:10%;
}
```

Right now, the font size and image size stays static, so when I resize the browser, the image eventually gets cut off, and the text expands vertically.

Comment: I posted an answer below. I hope I understood your question correctly. If I missed something, or you have questions, just let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You want responsive design. Essentially, responsive design is an approach of making the web-page look good in any browser or device. If you want to make the images shrink proportionally, then you need to set their `width` and `height` to certain percentage of their container, which, on the other hand should be a percentage of its container and so on. It is slightly more difficult to make the text shrink or enlarge upon window size change, since it you need media queries for that.

Read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp) tutorial to learn about responsive design and click on next chapter a few times, to make sure you read enough material about the topic in general. Use [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to set the `font-size` property depending on specific cases you define according to your taste and needs.

Answer (score 1):

check this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/khbqwb7v/3/)

```css
#flexbox { 
display: flex;
margin: 5%;
}

#text { 
font-size: 10vw; 
}

#image { 
height: 40vw;
width :40vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox">
    <div id="text">Some text</div>
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Dell_Logo.png" id="image" width="400" height="414" alt="">
</div>
```